# LCD Panel for Ubuntu

Tags: display, panel

i'm searching for an LCD Panel for a 5,25" slot (CD Slot in a "normal" PC case) which is compatible with Linux Ubuntu.
I found some on the web, but most are just controlled by a software for Windows.
I want to show the CPU/Memory Usage, System Temperature, System Time, Uptime, Memory used on HDD sdc/md1 (my RAID1 is called md1) ect.
I want to use it to show those information's on my HP Proliant N36L Micro Server which is at eye-line on my desk.
I got a external USB port on my Bord and a x16 and a x1 PCIe where i could plug it.

Does someone know a Panel which supports this for Ubuntu?

Scincerly, Alex

Comment: Excellent question, I've just built a file server raid system based on ubuntu and I've been writing scripts so that when I log into it, most of the information (like what you've mentioned) is pumped out at the top of my terminal since I plan to be using it headless most of the time (although I'm actually using it as a full computer for the time being). And this is an excellent question since that would be more akin to what I'm after. As a result of your question I have been googling it myself and haven't come up with much (the one I did find is below).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, I have just been looking for this myself (at your prompting) and the best I've come up with at this stage is a [20x2 LCD display](http://www.ncixus.com/products/?sku=33470) (likely HD44780 or compatible unit) which would have some micro-controller behind it. On that page I saw that someone had already mentioned LCD Smartie (a site I frequented year ago)which could be used to control it. But it's MS Windows only, and so it got me to searching.

There doesn't seem to be too much out there aimed in our market, but this would be a relatively easy project to undertake.

Adafruit has a project on a [Raspberry Pi based LCD Display](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi.pdf) version (The Raspberry Pi runs Raspian which is another Debian derivative as is Ubuntu). They have details for getting a python script up and running for it.

I also found the `man` page for [LCD Daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/LCDd.8.html) on ubuntu.com which purports [LCDproc was up and running in Natty](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/lcdproc) and should be `apt-get install`-able in current versions. *edit: it is [Ubuntu `lcdproc` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lcdproc)*

## tldr;

I personally think the first one I linked above is a little pricey and it would be a fun project to do yourself, and I'm actually now thinking of doing this myself. the 16x2, 20x2 LCDs are cheap and readily available everywhere, although I'd probably go a nicer OLED screen (or screens, possibly go two!) like the [1.3" OLEDs from adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/product/938).

Hopefully one of the links above will whet your appetite and inspire you to create your own.

Comment: since writing this about an hour ago, I've had 20+ tabs open researching this, and there are some VERY nice displays out there for very cheap $$$. For the hacker/hobbyist this would be a very fun little project